# If oauth is stateless how can google destroy oauth token?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-oauth

I know how oauth works, after successfully authenticated you make requests with that jwt tokens.

But the problem is how can i track how many active tokens exists or destroy tokens before it expires. Lets assume google or github, when you authenticate with oauth and they give you access token, also you can track or destroy tokens on their dashboard. So how they know my token is not valid anymore. The only way i though is they also establish session when access token granted.

But the problem is they have to check that session still valid or exists on every request. 
If they check it on every request where is the point of stateless?

Comment: OAuth2 doesn't have to be stateless or use JWTs. If the service provider has a dashboard listing the tokens, then that isn't stateless - they are stored by the provider and presumably checked when you access the corresponding resource.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* stateless and there are *no* sessions.
An OAuth implementation that wishes to revoke tokens does so using token revocation lists that are accessible by all of the endpoints.